# Title of a chapter without the word "chapter"

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

At the end of my dissertation, I have a plan for future work. My question is How can I make the title "Future work" appear as a chapter heading without the word "Chapter" and also number as well as I want it to appear in the list of contents. Can you suggest what should I do?

Comment: You could start your 'Future work' with a little present for the present time (pun intended ;-)) by providing a MWE

Comment: `\chapter*{...}` is the usual way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer that question, since you don't tell us which class you are using. Here's a possibility, which assumes that you are using the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Normal chapter}
\chapter*{Future work}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Future work}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but this is unnumbered.

Comment: Since the OP wrote “without the word "Chapter" and also number”, I thought that they meant unnumbered too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The original question is tagged with `titlesec`, so it is very likely that a `titlesec` related answer is requested -- the question is unclear, though.

Comment: i saw some of your recent edits. There is no real point in fixing typos (especially single typos) years later. I suggest to let those questions rest in peace.

Comment: @Johannes_B In general, I agree, but I suppose that it is still important to correct old typos when they are located in the titles of the posts, because if you are doing a search, you might miss a post due to a misspelled word.